# Get reply from remote server using C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get data from a remote server using C#. I tried using a simple script to see if "it works", but I'm not getting a response. The same script works on a local server, so I'd like to know how I can do it.

This is my C# code:

```
IEnumerator Sayhi()
{
    WWWForm sendInfo = new WWWForm();
    sendInfo.AddField("function", function);

    WWW www = new WWW(bl_LoginDataBase.Instance.GetUrl(bl_LoginDataBase.URLType.CallFunction), sendInfo);
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log(www.text);
}
```

And the PHP code:

```
<?php
echo "Hi";
```

I expected the `Debug.Log(www.text);` to print `Hi`, which it does if I use a local machine (`http://192.168.0.whatever`), but the remote server (`http://whatever.example.com`) doesn't return anything. I tried making the php fail so it returns an error, make a database and return some values from there, but nothing. I'd like to point out it *does* work on a local server, and works as intended.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** By the way, if I access `http://www.whatever.example.com/Function.php` via browser, it shows the `echo` result.

Comment: I dont know what WWWForm type is but hopefully it gives you an http status return code. What is it?

Comment: And, what is enumerable about that code?

Comment: @Crowcoder It doesn't return any http status return code. I'm using Unity to run it, by the way. It *will* be enumerable, but that's not something related to the question. It could very well be a regular function calling the WWWForm.

Comment: Your browser will be doing a GET request but it looks like you are crafting a POST request in your code but I can't be sure since I'm unfamiliar with that library.

Comment: @Crowcoder That's the way it's done in Unity. IEnumerator is because it's a coroutine. However, you are correct, by passing a `WWWForm` the OP is actually doing a POST rather than a GET. Not sure if that makes a difference in PHP, though.

Comment: According the the WWWForm documentation the default is GET so that explains why it works on localhost. I don't see an http status property but I do see an error property. Did you check it? Also, maybe you have an exception so a try/catch is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has built in classes and methods to help you perform such tasks.You can use the WebClient class to connect to web servers (using GET or POST) and even send form values to it easily. See below:

```
string url ="http://www.whatever.example.com/Function.php";

var reqparam = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

reqparam.Add("name", "John Doe");

try
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {

     byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", parameters);

     string output = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);

     }
}
catch (Exception x)
{
   //an error occured
}
```

The variable **output** will contain the response you want "Hi".

Comment: This will block while the Unity WWWForm will not. It apparently was designed that way to prevent the game from stopping while background requests are made, which makes sense.

Comment: Im not familiar with unity but yes this code will block the current thread. You can use the client.UploadStringAsync method instead, this does not block the current UI.